# Filter rows of two datasets based on the content of a column in common

Tags: python, excel, database, dataset, orange

I have two large datasets with one column in common; I have to filter these tow datasets, row by row, based on the content of the cells in the column in common: if the value of a cell in the column in common in dataset 1 is also present in a cell of the column in common in dataset 2, i have to keep the row with this value in both datasets; if a value in the column in common is present only in dataset 1 or in dataset 2 i have to delete the row with this value.
[exlample datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVe8W.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this limited explanation of the problem try importing the two datasets into Pandas dataframes and then merging on the common column.

please see the examples in the pandas documentation. carefully selecting the `how=` argument of the merge will accomplish your filtering for you. based on your description, `how='inner', on='common column'` might be your solution.

see documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html